# How can I speedily check the existence of a large number of records in the database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

At some point in my Rails application, I retrieve a large number of ActiveRecord objects from the cache. However, it's possible that some of these records have been deleted from the database itself since they were stored in the cache, so I loop the records and check each one to see if it exists. This takes quite a lot of time. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: That's only one of the [two hardest things in computer science](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html)

Comment: @Danny - how is your comment helpful?  I do not see why anyone would simply say this is really hard and consider it remotely helpful in any way.  Are you saying forget it, redesign your code?

Comment: @jimmcnamara - Thanks for your feedback! You're right, I wasn't particularly clear in my comment.  All I wanted to add was recognition that this is one of the harder things to get right in coding, hopefully with a touch of humor.

Comment: Can't you delete the related object from the cache when deleting a record from the database (using ActiveRecord callbacks)? That way you don't have to loop and check if it exists.

Comment: I guess you should rethink about your database structure and if this is not possible then think about "sphinx" or better "thinking sphnix" it provides much faster caching then active record!

Comment: I actually appreciated the response from @Danny, because seeing the term "cache invalidation" made me think that I need to actually invalidate the cache when objects are deleted, so that way it's always empty or valid, and I won't have to do this expensive loop every time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there a reason why you are not deleting the records from the cache when they are deleted from the database?

If you are going to be storing these records in the cache and need them in sync with the db, then when you remove them from the db make sure to remove their existence from the cache as well, therefore saving yourself the expensive query of having to check for redundant data later.

Answer (score 1):

This could also be considered a db design problem and not a really rails issue.  Taking that point of view, can you add an AUTO INCREMENT field with a unique index to your table?

The active record query interface has to rely on the database ultimately for lookups even when doing a record existence check.  So no matter how good the interface is if the db has to do lots of work it will take time, and is not a rails "fault".  Make it as fast as possible for the db to validate the record you want.

If you are familiar with oracle, this is the same idea as storing an oracle rowid in a query to be able to validate an existing record later on.

As Danny seems to indicate, maybe caching loads of records and using them a lot later is bad idea for your app. Can you read, and then immediately process your record?

Neither of these suggestions is a quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

If the number of records you are checking is truly massive, then you may be able to amortize the cost of shipping them one-by-one by doing a bulk transfer: create a temporary table, do a big insert into it of the rows you pulled out of your cache, and then join the temporary table against the original table. Your DBMS will then do the looping for you.

Answer (score 0):

If the results from cache include the primary keys of the records you're interested in, you can pretty easily filter the results by selecting just those keys from the database and seeing what comes back. Then just kick out stale records and you're good to go.

```
results_from_cache = $redis.get("users")

cached_user_ids = results_from_cache.map(&:id)
actual_user_ids = User.where(id: user_ids).pluck(:id)

results_minus_stale = results_from_cache.select do |user|
  actual_user_ids.include?(user.id)
end
```